# Redirect to index.php and remove trailing slash .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, webserver

There appears to be many questions like this here but can't find an answer that fits my current code:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

This redirects everything to `public/index.php` which works fine but I want to get rid of the trailing slash so that `example.com/foo/` becomes `example.com/foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a trailing slash removal code **before your current rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

## forward all requests to public/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: The above code redirects `foo/` to `public/foo/`. I need to "hide" `public` in browser URL.

Comment: Sorry I am using a boilerplate from a long time ago https://pastebin.com/sKp3nWvG

Comment: Yup still the same :(

Comment: Well it's in localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182379/discussion-between-anubhava-and-imb).